# Read class methods properties in mvc4 T4 template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, t4

i am working on T4 Templates in web api project in ASP.Net MVC3. i need to get  classes and methods from business layer and create cs files using .tt files. also i aneed to get methods only have   [PrivateApi] tag.

this is my t4 template class.

> ```
> <# 
>
> Assembly ab =  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
>     .Where(b=>b.GetName().Name.Trim().ToLower() == "Empite.Give360.Business".ToLower())
>     .FirstOrDefault() as Assembly; 
>
> foreach (var type in ab.GetTypes())
> {  
>     if (type.Name.EndsWith("Service") && type.IsInterface )
>     {
>
>         CreateAPI(type);
>         SaveOutput(type.Name + "API.cs");
>
>     }
> }          
>
> DeleteOldOutputs();    #>
> ```
>
> <#+    public void CreateAPI(Type businessObjType ) {#>
>
> public class <#=        businessObjType.Name.Substring(1) #>API : <#= 
>   businessObjType.Name #>API {
>           } public interface <#=        businessObjType.Name #>API { } <#+    } #>

this is generated CS file

```
public class DonationServiceAPI : IDonationServiceAPI
{

}
public interface IDonationServiceAPI
{
}
```

This is the class that i need to reproduce

```
public class DonationService : IDonationService
{

 private readonly IDonationRepository _donationRepository;
        private readonly IDonationStatusTypeRepository _donationStatusTypeRepository;
        private readonly IPayrollDeductionRepository _payrollDeductionRepository;

        public DonationService() : this(new DonationRepository(),new DonationStatusTypeRepository(),new PayrollDeductionRepository())
        {

        }

        public DonationService(IDonationRepository donationRepository,IDonationStatusTypeRepository donationStatusTypeRepository,IPayrollDeductionRepository payrollDeductionRepository)
        {
            _donationRepository = donationRepository;
            _donationStatusTypeRepository = donationStatusTypeRepository;
            _payrollDeductionRepository = payrollDeductionRepository;
        }

 [PrivateApi]
  public ServiceResponse<Donation> GetDonationByDonationId(int donationId)
        {
            var donationObj = _donationRepository.Get(donationId);
            return new ServiceResponse<Donation>(donationObj);
        }
}
```

i'm new comer to T4 Templates and Does anyone know how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you the full answer but start at [ST4bby](https://github.com/jbubriski/ST4bby) for some example code to build from. It uses a RDB as base for which classes to create but does loop and does input classes to VS.